# Error rendering font icon in Openlayers 5

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers

I am using a true type font called "Geosiana Desa" but the character "o" is not fully rendered as seen in the picture. I tried changing the size and textBaseline with no success. Any clue?
In Chrome the font is truncated (see the image), in Firefox the characters are not well displayed.
Below, an example of the style applied:

```
symText  = new Text({
  font:"normal 18px Geosiana Desa" ,    
  textBaseline:'top' ,
  scale: 2,
  text: "o",
  fill: new Fill({
    color: “blue”,
  }),

});

newStyle = new Style({
  text: symText,
});
```

> Openlayers_rendering_ttf

[image: Openlayers_rendering_ttf]

Comment: As a workaround you could use   `text: "\no",` which places an empty line above the symbol so the top isn't truncated.  If you do that I suggest you change to `textBaseline:'bottom'` and set an `offsetY` to compensate.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/icon-n7901

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work.